# Users not seeing correct value in table

Tags: android

Hi I have an android application which has a list of values like

```
: Waiting for Supervisor Approval
: Wating for COO Approval
```

etc.

But when users see these values it in their table:

```
:Watingforsupervisorwaitingforsupervisor

:Waitingforcooapprovalwaitingforcooapprovalwaitingforcooapproval.
```

I am not sure how can debug and resolve this issue?

Comment: Please post the code used to display the values. Without seeing your code, noone can help you.

Comment: try adding %20 for space!